# Riemannian geometry: ...Why is it called 'Exponential' map?

Tags: exponentiation, riemannian-geometry

The exponential map $exp_{p}:T_{p}M \to M$ given a suitable $v \in T_{p}M$, returns $p$, displaced along *the* geodesic uniquely determined by $(p,v) \in TM$ for unit "time".

So, what does the above have to do with the familiar concept/s of **exponentiation**?
Why does this map carry this name?

Comment: In the case of matrix groups, it really is the matrix exponential.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at the following figure (from an analysis textbook). For more background, in particular in connection with Lie algebras/groups see the Wikipedia article about the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map). The exponential series does indeed appear there.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The function $f(t)=\mathrm{e}^{at}$ can be viewed as the solution of the initial value problem:
$$
x'=ax, \quad x(0)=1.
$$
More generally, if $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $u_0\in\mathbb R^n$, then the solution of 
the
initial value problem:
$$
x'=Ax, \quad x(0)=u_0,
$$
is $u(t)=\mathrm{e}^{tA}u_0$, where $\mathrm{e}^{tA}$ is the exponential of the matrix $A$. It $A$ possessed imaginary eigenvalues, then $u(t)$ returns to a multiple of itself, for suitable initial $u_0$.

Comment: You could be a bit more concrete about what the underlying manifolds are for which this makes the connection to the differential geometric definition