# What is exponential map in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is $\exp_{q}(v)$ a projection of point $q$ to some point $q'$ along the geodesic whose tangent (right?) at $q$ is the vector $v$? And so $\exp_{q}(v)$ is the projection of point $q$ to some point along the geodesic between $q$ and $q'$?

(Another post gives an explanation: [Riemannian geometry: ...Why is it called 'Exponential' map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/633477/577710)
So now I'm wondering how we know where $q$ exactly falls on the geodesic after it travels for a unit amount of time. Does it uniquely depend on $p, v, M$ only, is it affected by any other parameters as well, or is it arbitrarily set to any point in the geodesic?)

The reason that it is called exponential map seems to be that the function satisfy that two images' multiplication $\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)$ equals the image of the two independent variables' addition (to some degree)?

But that simply means a exponential map is sort of (inexact) homomorphism. Is there any other reasons for this naming?

---

(To make things clearer, what's said above is about exponential maps of manifolds, and what's said below is mainly about exponential maps of Lie groups. And I somehow 'apply' the theory of exponential maps of Lie group to exponential maps of Riemann manifold (for I thought they were 'consistent' with each other). What I tried to do by experimenting with these concepts and notations is not only to understand each of the two exponential maps, but to connect the two concepts, to make them consistent, or to find the **relation or similarity** between the two concepts. Now it seems I should try to look at the **difference** between the two concepts as well.)

It seems that, according to p.388 of Spivak's Diff Geom, $\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)=\exp_{q}((v_1+v_2)+[v_1, v_2]+...)$, where $[\ ,\ ]$ is a bilinear function in Lie algebra (I don't know exactly what Lie algebra is, but I guess for tangent vectors $v_1, v_2$ it is (or can be) inner product, or perhaps more generally, a 2-tensor product (mapping two vectors to a number) (length) times a unit vector (direction)). It seems $[v_1, v_2]$ 'measures' the difference between $\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)$ and $\exp_{q}(v_1+v_2)$ to the first order, so I guess it plays a role similar to one that first order derivative $/1!$ plays in function's expansion into power series.

With such comparison of $[v_1, v_2]$ and 2-tensor product, and of  $[v_1, v_2]$ and first order derivatives, perhaps $\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)=\exp_{q}((v_1+v_2)+[v_1, v_2]+ T_3\cdot e_3+T_4\cdot e_4+...)$, where $T_i$ is $i$-tensor product (length) times a unit vector $e_i$ (direction) and where $T_i$ is similar to $i$th derivatives$/i!$ and measures the difference to the $i$th order.

(According to the wiki articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory) mentioned in the answers to the above post, it seems $\exp_{q}(v))$ does have an power series expansion quite similar to that of $e^x$, and possibly $T_i\cdot e_i$ can, in some cases, written as an extension of $[\ , \ ]$, e.g. $[v_1,[v_1,v_2]]$ so that $T_i$ is $i$-tensor product but remains a function of two variables $v_1,v_2$.)

Besides, if so we have $\exp_{q}(tv_1)\exp_{q}(tv_2)=\exp_{q}(t(v_1+v_2)+t^2[v_1, v_2]+ t^3T_3\cdot e_3+t^4T_4\cdot e_4+...)$.

I'm not sure if my understanding is roughly correct.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are two types of exponential maps typically used in differential geometry: one for [Riemannian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)), which you refer to in your question, and one for [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)), which Spivac is referring to. The expression $\exp(u)\exp(v)=\exp(u+v+[u,v]+\dots)$ is known as the [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and applies specifically to Lie groups.

Comment: Trying to understand the second variety. Where can we find some typical geometrical examples of exponential maps for Lie groups?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by $\exp_q$? Specifically, what are the domain the codomain? At the beginning you seem to be talking about a Riemannian exponential map $\exp_q:T_qM\to M$ where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, but by the end you are instead talking about the map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ where $G$ is a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra. These maps have the same name and are very closely related, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @Narasimham Typical simple examples are the one demensional ones: $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is the ordinary exponential function, but we can think of $\mathbb{R}^+$ as a Lie group under multiplication and $\mathbb{R}$ as an Abelian Lie algebra with $[x,y]=0$ $\forall x,y$. Fitting this into the more abstract, manifold based definitions/constructions can be a useful exercise.

Comment: Yes, I do confuse the two concepts, or say their similarity in names confuses me a bit. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 32):

---

**Why it is called the exponential**

The reason it's called the exponential is that in the case of matrix manifolds,
the abstract version of $\exp$ defined in terms of the manifold structure coincides
with the "matrix exponential" $exp(M) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^\infty M^n/n!$.

---

**A concrete example, the unit circle**

For example, let's consider the unit circle $M \equiv \{ x \in \mathbb R^2 : |x| = 1 \}$.
This can be viewed as a Lie group
$M = G = SO(2) = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} : \theta \in \mathbb R \right\}$.

---

**The unit circle: Tangent space at the identity, the hard way**

We can derive the lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of this Lie group $G$ of this "formally"
by trying computing the tangent space of identity. To do this, we first need a
useful definition of the tangent space. One possible definition is to use
the definition of the space of curves $\gamma_{\alpha}: [-1, 1] \rightarrow M$, where
the curves are such that $\gamma(0) = I$. Then the
tangent space $T_I G$ is the collection of the curve derivatives $\frac{d(\gamma(t)) }{dt}|_0$.
Let's calculate the tangent space  of $G$ at the identity matrix $I$, $T_I G$:

$$
\gamma_\alpha(t) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\alpha t) & \sin (\alpha t) \\
-\sin (\alpha t) & \cos (\alpha t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is a legal curve because the image of $\gamma$ is in $G$, and $\gamma(0) = I$. We can
differentiate this and compute $\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma_\alpha(t))|_0$ to get:

\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma_\alpha(t))|_0 = 
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\alpha t) & \sin (\alpha t) \\
-\sin (\alpha t) & \cos (\alpha t)
\end{bmatrix}|_0 \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{d(\cos (\alpha t))}{dt}|_0 & \frac{d(\sin (\alpha t))}{dt}|_0 \\
\frac{d(-\sin (\alpha t))}{dt}|_0 & \frac{d(\cos (\alpha t))}{dt}|_0
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha\sin (\alpha t)|_0 & \alpha\cos (\alpha t)|_0  \\
-\alpha\cos (\alpha t)|_0 & -\alpha\sin (\alpha t)|_0
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & \alpha  \\
-\alpha & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
= \text{skew symmetric matrix}
\end{align*}

So we get that the tangent space at the identity $T_I G = \{ S \text{ is $2\times2$ matrix} : S + S^T = 0 \}$

Now recall that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of a Lie group $G$ is
**defined to be** the tangent space at the identity. So we have that
$\mathfrak g = T_I G = \text{$2\times2$ skew symmetric matrices}$.

---

**The unit circle: Tangent space at the identity by logarithmization**

On the other hand, we can also compute the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ / the tangent
space at the identity $T_I G$ "completely informally",
by "logarithmizing" the group. We know that the group of rotations $SO(2)$ consists
of orthogonal matrices
group, so every element $U \in G$ satisfies $UU^T = I$. We can logarithmize this
condition as follows:

$$
M = G = \{ U : U U^T = I \} \\
\mathfrak g = \log G = \{ \log U : \log (U U^T) = \log I \} \\
\mathfrak g = \log G = \{ \log U : \log (U) + \log(U^T) = 0 \} \\
\mathfrak g = \log G = \{ \log U : \log (U) + \log(U)^T = 0 \} \\
\mathfrak g = \log G = \{ S : S + S^T = 0 \} \\
$$

We got the same result: $\mathfrak g$ is the group of skew-symmetric matrices by
following the physicist derivation of taking a $\log$ of the group elements.

---

**The unit circle: The exponential map**

Now, it should be intuitively clear that if we got from $G$ to $\mathfrak g$
using $\log$, we ought to have an inverse $\exp: \mathfrak g \rightarrow G$ which
does the opposite. Indeed, this is *exactly* what it means to have an exponential
map: we can go from elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ / the tangent space
at the identity $T_I G$ to the Lie group $G$.

---

**The unit circle: Computing the exponential map**

Assume we have a $2 \times 2$ skew-symmetric matrix $S$. We want to show that its
exponential lies in $G$:

$$
\exp(S) = \exp \left (\begin{bmatrix} 0 & s \\ -s & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty S^n/n!
$$

We can compute this by making the following observation:

\begin{align*}
S^2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & s \\ -s & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & s \\ -s & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
-s^2 & 0 \\ 0 & -s^2
\end{bmatrix}
= -\begin{bmatrix}
s^2 & 0 \\ 0 & s^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

We immediately generalize, to get $S^{2n} = -(1)^n
\begin{bmatrix}
s^{2n} & 0 \\ 0 & s^{2n}
\end{bmatrix}$

This gives us $S^{2n+1} = S^{2n}S$:

\begin{align*}
S^{2n+1} = S^{2n}S =
(-1)^n
\begin{bmatrix}
s^{2n} & 0 \\ 0 & s^{2n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & s \\ -s & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
=
(-1)^n
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & s^{2n+1} \\ -s^{2n+1} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

We can now compute the exponential as:

\begin{align*}
&\exp(S) = I + S + S^2 + S^3 + .. = \\
&(I + S^2/2! + S^4/4! + \cdots) + (S + S^3/3! + S^5/5! + \cdots) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
1 - s^2/2! + s^4/4! + \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 - s^2/2! + s^4/4! + \cdots
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & s - s^3/3! + s^5/5! + \cdots \\
s - s^3/3! + s^5/5! + \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(s) & \sin(s) \\
-sin(s) & \cos(s)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

We get the result that we expect: We get a rotation matrix $\exp(S) \in SO(2)$.
We can check that this $\exp$ is indeed an inverse to $\log$.

---

**Why skew-symmetric?**

What does it *mean* that the tangent space at the identity $T_I G$ of the
group of rotations are the skew-symmetric matrices?

One explanation is to think of these as *curl*, where a *curl* is a sort
of "infinitesimal rotation". See that a skew symmetric matrix
$S \equiv \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ -b & a
\end{bmatrix}$

can be viewed as having two vectors $S_1 = (a, b)$ and $S_2 = (-b, a)$, which
represents an infinitesimal rotation from $(a, b)$ to $(-b, a)$.

This is skew-symmetric because rotations in 2D have an *orientation*. Flipping
the order of the vectors gives us the rotations in the opposite order: It takes
clockwise to anti-clockwise and anti-clockwise to clockwise. If we wish
to fancy, we can talk about this [in terms of exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Infinitesimal_rotations)

See the picture which shows the skew-symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and its transpose as "2D orientations"

[image: diagram-skew-symmetric]

---

**The unit circle: What about the other tangent spaces?!**

So far, I've only spoken about the lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ / the tangent space at
the identity $T_I G$. What about all of the other tangent spaces?

A [very cool theorem of matrix Lie theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389983/explicit-description-of-tangent-spaces-of-on) tells
us that the tangent space at some point $P$, $T_P G$ is always going
to be translates of $T_I G$. Formally, we have the equality:

$$T_P G = P T_I G = \{ P T : T \in T_I G \}$$

This lets us immediately know that whatever theory we have discussed "at the identity"
can be easily translated to "any point" $P \in G$, by simply multiplying with the point $P$.

---

**Recap**
We saw the following equivalences:

- We have a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, which is the
  tangent space at the identity $T_I G$.
- For this, computing the Lie algebra by using the "curves" definition co-incides
  with simply invoking $\log: G \rightarrow \mathfrak g$ on the definiton of the matrix group.
- Vice versa, the $\exp$ (inverse of $\log$) can be computed from the series
  definition, giving us a map $\exp: \mathfrak g \rightarrow G$.
- These maps allow us to go from the "local behaviour" to the "global behaviour".
- We gained an intuition for the concrete case of $G = SO(2)$, $\mathfrak g$ as
  skew-symmetric matrices, and *why* skew-symmetric matrices are the "infinitesimal rotations"
- We refer to the fact that if we know $\mathfrak g$/$T_I G$, we automatically know
  *all* tangent spaces due to the group being a Lie group. Hence, knowing the lie
  algebra $\mathfrak g$ is "as good as" knowing the tangent space structure *everywhere*.

**A summary picture:**
[image: summary-relationships]

Comment: I see $S^1$ is homeomorphism to rotational group $SO(2)$, and the Lie algebra is defined to be tangent space at (1,0) in $S^1$ (or at $I$ in $SO(2)$. Exponential maps from tangent space to the manifold, if put in matrix ‘representation’, since powers of a vector $v$ of tangent space (in matrix ‘representation’, i.e. an anti symmetric matrix $\lambda [0, 1; -1, 0]$, say $\lambda T$ ) alternates between $\lambda^n\cdot T$ or $\lambda^n\cdot I$, leading to that exponentials of the vector‘s matrix representation being combination of $\cos(v), \sin(v)$ which is (matrix repre of) a point in $S^1$.

Comment: Since the matrices involved only have two independent components we can repeat the process similarly using complex number, (v is represented by $0+i\lambda$, identity of $S^1$ by $ 1+i\cdot0$) i.e. $\exp(v)=\exp(i\lambda)$ = power expansion = $cos(\lambda)+\sin(\lambda)$. (For both repre have two independents components, the calculations are almost identical.) However, this complex number ‘repre’ can’t be easily extended to slanting tangent space in 2-dim and higher dim.

Comment: Should be ‘Exponential maps from tangent space to the manifold, if put in matrix ‘representation’, are called exponential, since powers of...’.     
Besides, I’m not sure why Lie algebra is defined this way, perhaps it’s because that makes tangent spaces of all Lie groups easily inferred from Lie algebra?

Comment: Also, in this example $\exp(v_1)\exp(v_2)= \exp(v_1+v_2)$ and $[v_1, v_2]=AB-BA=0$, where A B are matrix repre of the two vectors. I’m not sure if these are always true for exponential maps of Riemann manifolds.

Comment: @CharlieChang Indeed, this example $SO(2) \simeq U(1)$ so it's commutative. To the see the "larger scale behavior" wth non-commutativity, simply repeat the same story, replacing $SO(2)$ with $SO(3)$. All the explanations work out, but rotations in 3D do not commute; This gives the example where the lie group $G = SO(3)$ isn't commutative, while the lie algbera `$\mathfrak g$ is [thanks to being a vector space].

Comment: @CharlieChang The reason the lie algebra is defined this way is a slightly long story. There are two definitions of lie algebra of a lie group: (1) The tangent space at the identity $T_I G$. (2) The vector space of "left invariant vector fields of a lie group". We can show that these two definitions are isomorphic. I picked (1) for convenience; The "real definition" (insofar as such a thing exists) is (2). [Here is the wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#The_Lie_algebra_associated_with_a_Lie_group). I personally find the $T_I G$ definition far more intuitive...

Comment: ... but one can see the motivation for definition (2) as well. The idea is that we have a vector space of vector fields, and the commutator measures the failure of the vector fields to "commute". However, this is an infinite dimensional vector space. For each point $p \in M$ we can pick a tangent vector in $T_p M$ to build a vector space. In the Lie group case, we can isolate  collection of "very nice vector fields" (the left invariant vector fields) which are _finite dimensional_, and have dimension equal to the manifold. So $\mathfrak g$ is a collection of "good vector fields"...

Comment: ... since these "good vector fields" are translation invariant (left invariant), knowing their value at one location, $T_I G$ allows us to push the vector everywhere, and learn the value throughout the whole group. This gives an isomorphism between $T_I G$ [the tangent space at the identity[ and the whole collection of left invariant vector fields. Perhaps another question of "intuition of equivalence between the definitions of lie algebra" is a good place to discuss this :)