# Is there a similar formula to BCH formula for exponential maps in Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

This follows from another post: [What is exponential map in differential geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766220/577710). Actually it's implied there, but not explicitly stated.

In exponential maps of Lie group, we have BCH formula $\exp(X)\exp_{q}(Y)=\exp((X+Y)+[X, Y]+ \dots)$

Is there a similar formula
$\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)=\exp_{q}((v_1+v_2)+[v_1, v_2]+ \dots)$?

Considering there is an analog between operation of tangent vectors $X_e,Y_e$ (or $v_1, v_2$ in the above formula) and operations of vector spaces (tangent spaces of Lie groups) $\widetilde{X},\widetilde{Y}$, namely $[X_e,Y_e]=[\widetilde{X},\widetilde{Y}]_e$, we may define $[v_1, v_2]$ in general for Riemannian manifolds (or we can't do so for those manifolds we can't **impose Lie group structure** on?), therefore the above formula seems to exist (or only exist for manifolds w Lie group structure?); unless in all Riemannian manifolds $[v_1, v_2]=0$, which implies we always have $\exp_{q}(v_1)\exp_{q}(v_2)=\exp_{q}(v_1+v_2)$.

Comment: What does $[v_1,v_2]$ even mean? Granted, @Kajelad's question is even more basic.

Comment: What does the juxtaposition $\exp_q(X)\exp_q(Y)$ mean? On a Riemannian manifold, there isn't a way to multiply points on the manifold.

Comment: I see I seem not to have understood [,] for Lie group well.